# How to print a time field (declared as a float) in Qweb Reports with the float_time widget?

Tags: widget, report, odoo-8, odoo, qweb

When I want to print a date in a Qweb Reports I use this simple widget:

```xml
<span t-field="o.event_date" t-field-options='{"widget": "date"}' />
```

But when I want to print time I cannot use this other widget because it doesn't work, I think it doesn't exist:

```xml
<span t-field="o.event_time" t-field-options='{"widget": "float_time"}' />
```

Is there an easy way to make this widget work in the Qweb Reports?

I have to use this no intuitive way instead of that widget:

```xml
<t t-esc="'%02d:%02d' % (int(str(o.event_time).split('.')[0]), int(float(str('%.2f' % o.event_time).split('.')[1])/100*60))" />
```

By the way, I declared `event_time` as a float:

```python
event_time = fields.Float("Time", size=5)
```

Comment: would it work to declare `event_time` to be a datetime, and then use `t-field-options='{"widget": "time"}'`  ?

Comment: It seems there is no widget named "time"; I withdraw my comment :-(

Answer (score 3):

You can add for the new module for the float_time widget you can add this format.js in your module

```js
openerp.float_time_hms = function(instance){



    original_format_value = instance.web.format_value;
    instance.web.format_value = function (value, descriptor, value_if_empty) {
        switch (descriptor.widget || descriptor.type || (descriptor.field && descriptor.field.type)) {
            case 'float_time':
                var pattern = '%02d:%02d:%02d';
                if (value < 0) {
                    value = Math.abs(value);
                    pattern = '-' + pattern;
                }
                var hour = Math.floor(value);
                var min = (value % 1) * 60;
                min = Math.round((min + 0.0001)*1000)/1000;
                if (min >= 60){
                    min = 0;
                    hour = hour + 1;
                }
                sec = (min % 1) * 60;
                sec = Math.round((sec + .0001)*10000)/10000;
                if (sec >= 60){
                    sec = 0;
                    min = min + 1;
                }
                return _.str.sprintf(pattern, hour, min, sec);
        }
        return original_format_value(value, descriptor, value_if_empty);
    };

    original_parse_value = instance.web.parse_value;
    instance.web.parse_value = function (value, descriptor, value_if_empty) {
        switch (descriptor.widget || descriptor.type || (descriptor.field && descriptor.field.type)) {
            case 'float_time':
                var factor = 1;
                if (value[0] === '-') {
                    value = value.slice(1);
                    factor = -1;
                }
                var float_time_triad = value.split(":");
                if (float_time_triad.length != 3)
                    return factor * original_parse_value(value, {type: "float"});
                var hours = original_parse_value(float_time_triad[0], {type: "integer"});
                var minutes = original_parse_value(float_time_triad[1], {type: "integer"});
                var seconds = original_parse_value(float_time_triad[2], {type: "integer"});
                return factor * (hours + (minutes / 60) + (seconds / 3600) + .0001);
        }
        return original_parse_value(value, descriptor, value_if_empty);
    };

};
```

After that add this .js to your .xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <template id="assets_backend" name="float_time_hms assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
            <xpath expr="." position="inside">
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/float_time_hms/static/src/js/format.js"></script>
            </xpath>
        </template>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

Answer (score 1):

This question was asked for Odoo 8, but in newer versions (at least since Odoo 12, maybe earlier) it has been possible to use the float_time widget in Qweb like this:

```xml
<span t-field="o.event_time" t-options="{'widget': 'float_time'}" />
```